# looping through an array in : PHP

Tags: php, json

My JSON Array:

```
[\"{\\\"mapurl\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/maps.google.com\\\\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxx5,78.xxxxxx3\\\",\\\"caller\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxx\\\",\\\"id\\\":1,\\\"reciever\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxx\\\",\\\"timpestamp\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\",\"{\\\"mapurl\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/maps.google.com\\\\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxx,78.xxxxx\\\",\\\"caller\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxx\\\",\\\"id\\\":2,\\\"reciever\\\":\\\"+91xxxxx\\\",\\\"timpestamp\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\"]
```

I am passing this JSONArray as a part of POST Request in add Parameter.

My code for displaying the content of the Array

```
$jsonData = stripslashes($_POST['add']);
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);
foreach ($phpArray as $index => $record) 
{
 echo $record["caller"];
}
```

My Output is just two open curly brackets.

{{

I unable to understand whats wrong

Comment: Why are you stripping slashes ?

Comment: do a var_dump of $jsonData and see what is being received

Comment: Wait what? Why does it start with `["{"` and not with `[{`?

Comment: That's not json. `"}"mapurl"` is a flat-out syntax error.

Comment: [{"mapurl":"http:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps?q=17.xxxx,78.xxxx","caller":"+91xxxx","id":1,"reciever":"+91xxxx","timpestamp":"xxxx"},
{"mapurl":"http:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps?q=17.xxxxx,78.xxxxx","caller":"+91xxxxx","id":2,"reciever":"+91xxxxx","timpestamp":"xxxx"}] 

this is valid json.

Comment: MY aCtual JSONArray has MAgic Quotes enabled so i am using Stripslashes.I have editied the question with actual json data as i am recieveing from the android device

Comment: @Wrikken MY actual JSONArray has MAgic Quotes enabled so i am using Stripslashes.I have editied the question with actual json data as i am recieveing from the android device.

Comment: @exussum MY actual JSONArray has MAgic Quotes enabled so i am using Stripslashes.I have editied the question with actual json data as i am recieveing from the android device.

Comment: @MarcB MY actual JSONArray has MAgic Quotes enabled so i am using Stripslashes.I have editied the question with actual json data as i am recieveing from the android device.

Comment: magic_quotes? Good luck dealing with that festering pile of crap. That is probably the single most insanely moronic stupid design decision in recent computing history, and it's rightly been killed (tho, imho, killing wasn't good enough. it should have been tortured to death, revived, and then tortured some more)

Comment: @MarcB I am not using it wantedly...i am generating this data from a android device and it is doing so. :(

Comment: how is android adding the magic quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, There shouldn't be quotes around each array.

Fix what is generating it, if oyou cant the below will fix

```
$jsonData = stripslashes(stripslashes($jsonData));
$jsonData = str_replace(
  array('"{', '}"'),
  array('{', '}'),
  $jsonData
);

$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);
foreach ($phpArray as $index => $record) 
{
   echo $record["caller"];
}
```

Though use as a last resort, Fix the broken JSON before its sent is the best option. magic quotes is also removed from PHP. avoid using it

Output of above

+91xxxx+91xxxxx

Comment: I am using Stripslashes becuse magic quotes were enabbled....i have editted my question for actual JSON Array

Comment: Updates based on that

Comment: I am getting `Warning: Invalid Arguments Supplied for foreach() in ...`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c2ae9b67521edc99f3db59273e6d5ccaaaf8d86   - i took your json from above,

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your json sting.
Try this :

```
$post = '[{\\\"mapurl\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/maps.google.com\\\\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxx5,78.xxxxxx3\\\",\\\"caller\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxx\\\",\\\"id\\\":1,\\\"reciever\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxx\\\",\\\"timpestamp\\\":\\\"3\\\"},{\\\"mapurl\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/maps.google.com\\\\\\/maps?q=17.xxxxx,78.xxxxx\\\",\\\"caller\\\":\\\"+91xxxxxx\\\",\\\"id\\\":2,\\\"reciever\\\":\\\"+91xxxxx\\\",\\\"timpestamp\\\":\\\"3\\\"}]';

$jsonData = stripslashes(stripslashes($post));
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);
foreach ($phpArray as $index => $record) 
{
echo $record["caller"];
}
```